# Sending a message to multiple channel ID's from different servers with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot to send a welcome message in multiple servers that it is in. I'm having trouble getting it to work any help would be appreciated!

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
/// Send the message to a designated channel on a server
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === '677397408422035456');
/// Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
if (!channel) return;
/// Send the message, mentioning the member
channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
```

Right now I am using the channel ID but I assume using the server ID would be better and then just sending a message to the default channel on that server. I'm thinking it would be something along the lines of:

```
when member joins server
get server ID
get default channel
send welcome message to default channel of server tagging the user
```

I'm not super fluent in javascript so I'm not quite sure how to get this sudo code into actual code for the bot. Everything else my bot does works but now I'm trying to get welcome messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property of the member: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=guild.

To make the array for the welcome channels, define the array with var welcomeChannels = []. Then, in the ready event, do a `forEach()` loop on the channels and `.push()` the ids into the array. When someone joins, make it look for the channel in the server with another `for` loop and return and break the loop when it finds the channel in the server.

Comment: Right now im using the bot in only 3 servers including my own, is there a way to set 

(ch => ch.id === '677397408422035456')

equal to an array with each channel id in the array?

Comment: Are you looking to put every welcome channel into the array?

Comment: For now I wouldnt mind putting each channel into an array. Like I said, Im only using the bot in 3 servers and dont really plan on trying to make the bot into a huge thing for anyone.